# Extracting large data chunks from PostgreSQL into Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using `psycopg2` and `pandas` to extract data from Postgres.

`pandas.read_sql_query` supports Python "generator" pattern when providing `chunksize` argument. It's not very helpful when working with large datasets, since the whole data is initially retrieved from DB into client-side memory and later chunked into separate frames based on `chunksize`. Large datasets will easily run into out-of-memory problems with this approach.

Postgres/psycopg2 are addressing this problem with [server-side cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). But Pandas does not seem to be supporting it.

Instead of doing:

```
iter = sql.read_sql_query(sql,
      conn,
      index_col='col1',
      chunksize=chunksize)
```

I tried reimplementing it like this:

```
from pandas.io.sql import SQLiteDatabase

curs = conn.cursor(name='cur_name') # server side cursor creation
curs.itersize = chunksize

pandas_sql = SQLiteDatabase(curs, is_cursor=True)
iter = pandas_sql.read_query(
      sql,
      index_col='col1',
      chunksize=chunksize)
```

but it fails because Pandas tries to access `cursor.description`, which is NULL for some reason with server-side cursors (and idea why?).

What's the best approach to proceed?
Tnx

P.S.

- SQLiteDatabase is used with Postgres when SQLAlchemy is not available
- Feature request on Pandas - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35689

Answer (score 1):

You would need to rewrite pandas's `read_query()` not to use `cursor.description`. Simply pass a list of column names to `read_query()` to make it use that instead of cursor.description`:

```
import psycopg2
from pandas.io.sql import SQLiteDatabase, _convert_params

# modify read_query as you need and overwrite it
# added column names as argument
def read_query_modified(
    self,
    sql,
    columns,
    index_col=None,
    coerce_float=True,
    params=None,
    parse_dates=None,
    chunksize=None,
):

    args = _convert_params(sql, params)
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
    # columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]

    if chunksize is not None:
        return self._query_iterator(
            cursor,
            chunksize,
            columns,
            index_col=index_col,
            coerce_float=coerce_float,
            parse_dates=parse_dates,
        )
    else:
        data = self._fetchall_as_list(cursor)
        cursor.close()

        frame = _wrap_result(
            data,
            columns,
            index_col=index_col,
            coerce_float=coerce_float,
            parse_dates=parse_dates,
        )
        return frame

# replace read_query with your version
SQLiteDatabase.read_query = read_query_modified

chunksize = 2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mf port=5959 host=localhost user=mf_usr")
curs = conn.cursor(name='cur_name')
curs.itersize = chunksize

sql = 'select * from users where id = 366196'
columns = ['id', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'birth', 'gender', 'nationality']

pandas_sql = SQLiteDatabase(curs, is_cursor=True)
iter = pandas_sql.read_query(
      sql,
      columns,
      index_col='id',
      chunksize=chunksize)

for x in iter:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
       firstname    lastname birth gender nationality
id
366196   Michael  Kronberger  None   None          at
```

Comment: I actually tried something like this, but I am getting an exception on `execute` - `Cursor alread closed`. Any idea?

Comment: Using the code I posted ? Works fine for me fetching 500K records (chunksize = 2)

Comment: My mistake - works! I slightly improved your answer to prevent the need for passing `columns`

Answer (score 0):

I slightly improved @Maurice Meyer answer to prevent the need to pass `columns` as an argument:

```
class CustomSQLiteDatabase(SQLiteDatabase):

    def read_query(
        self,
        sql,
        index_col=None,
        coerce_float=True,
        params=None,
        parse_dates=None,
        chunksize=None,
    ):

        args = _convert_params(sql, params)
        self.con.execute(*args)

        if chunksize is not None:

            columns = None

            while True:
                data = self.con.fetchmany(chunksize)

                if not columns:
                    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in self.con.description]

                if type(data) == tuple:
                    data = list(data)
                if not data:
                    self.con.close()
                    break
                else:
                    yield _wrap_result(
                        data,
                        columns,
                        index_col=index_col,
                        coerce_float=coerce_float,
                        parse_dates=parse_dates,
                    )

        else:
            data = self._fetchall_as_list(self.con)
            columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in self.con.description]
            self.con.close()

            frame = _wrap_result(
                data,
                columns,
                index_col=index_col,
                coerce_float=coerce_float,
                parse_dates=parse_dates,
            )
            return frame
```